# Size does matter (aka making "More Stack Exchange Communities" bigger doesn't look good)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

I just noticed this:

> [image]

I am pretty sure it wasn't that big yesterday. Now there is nearly no space between "More Stack Exchange Communities" and "company blog" which, in my opinion, makes it look bad.

Since it's already ALL CAPS and **bold**, can the font size be reduced again?

Don't think it's browser related, but just in case I'm seeing this in Chrome 52, under Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 48.0. looks OK. https://i.imgur.com/a1nKc9r.png

Comment: @DavidPostill weird. Thanks!

Comment: No repro in chrome on linux

Comment: I see a totally different heading style in general: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DjD6B.png but that seems to be an IE/Edge-specific behavior.  Not sure if it did that before though.

Comment: @Troyen yeah same for me with Edge.

Comment: FWIW, it's looking normal again today.

Comment: @Troyen true, for me too in Chrome.

Comment: @edc hello world

Answer (score 3):

Whatever it was, this is now back to normal.

Either a Chrome bug that was silently fixed at some recent patch/update (Still Chrome 52, but forgot to copy the full version), or a fix on Stack Exchange side.

Comment: Fixed on our end with a style update, though I'm still not entirely sure what changed to break it in the first place.